# flutter - how can Listview be able to scroll as usual beside tabBar?

Tags: listview, dart, flutter, tabbar

I want to build a UI on the homescreen where there is a `Carousel` element and then `TabBar` below it.
I use `Listview` to hold it, but why is it when it scroll it's not as usual?
Scroll it apart between the list on the TabBar element and the whole element on the homescreen.

see this [image: GIF]

my code in body:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScopedModelDescendant<MainModel>(builder: (context, child, model) {
      return ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0), child: instance),
          TabBar(
            isScrollable: false,
            unselectedLabelColor: Color(0xffD8D8DC),
            labelColor: Colors.white,
            indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
            indicator: BubbleTabIndicator(
              indicatorHeight: 25.0,
              indicatorColor: Colors.black,
              tabBarIndicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
            ),
            tabs: <Widget>[
              Tab(text: "Categories"),
              Tab(text: "Popular"),
              Tab(text: "What's New"),
            ],
            controller: _carouselController,
          ),
          Container(
            height: 320.0,
            child: TabBarView(
              controller: _carouselController,
              children: <Widget>[
                model.isLoading ? LoadingProgress() : CategoriesTab(),
                PopularTab(),
                WhatsNewTab(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    });
  }
}

final List<String> imgList = [
  'https://image01.kota.com/20140403023925/0000/0000/0046/9681/13sep18bliblimcd.jpg',
  'http://pallibazar.com/pub/media/wysiwyg/images/sliders/top-slider-banner-grocery-2.jpg',
  'https://www.familydollar.com/content/dam/familydollar/1.14/FD84881_PTH_WeeklySlider_1.15.png',
  'http://www.beshoffbros.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Beshoff_Hake_Slider.jpg',
];

List<T> map<T>(List list, Function handler) {
  List<T> result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    result.add(handler(i, list[i]));
  }

  return result;
}

//Carousel
final CarouselSlider instance = CarouselSlider(
  items: imgList.map((url) {
    return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
              new BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black38,
                  blurRadius: 2.0,
                  spreadRadius: 1.0,
                  offset: new Offset(0.0, 1.0)),
            ]),
        child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
            child: CachedNetworkImage(
                imageUrl: url,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                fadeInCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                width: 700.0,
                placeholder: Center(
                  child: SpinKitFadingCube(
                    color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                    size: 30,
                  ),
                ))));
  }).toList(),
  viewportFraction: 0.9,
  aspectRatio: 2.0,
  autoPlay: true,
);
```

any answer will appretiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap your `carousel` inside a `Container`:

```
 Container(
 height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/3 ;
 child : instance
 ),
```

do the same for your tab bar :

```
 Container(
 height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/3 ;
 child : //Your TabBar here
 ),
```

after that insert them both on your parent `ListView` and done.This will also make the scrolling on each part of the screen independent of the other on their respective parts, but the can both be moved using parent list.

Comment: its great, but i haven't got the right position yet.
how to only listview parent that can be scrolling? then the list element in the tabBar follows